# MVC - How to maintain form state until logout

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm working on a MVC website where the user logs in and can enter information in an activity form. Once submitted, it displays the results. Say the person goes to other links on the website and then decides to go back to the activity form. Is there a way to so that my user's form fields,drop box,slider placement, etc. is still maintained? The only time the form should not be maintained is until the user logs out.

Here is my code so far:

**View - Activities**

```
@model Project.Models.ActivityModel
@using (Html.BeginForm())
 {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Activity_CityName)
    <div class="editor-label">   
        <strong>@Html.LabelFor(x => x.Activity_StartDate)</strong>
    </div> 
    <div class="editor-field">
        <input id="checkin" type="text" name="Activity_StartDate" />
    </div>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Activity_EndDate)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Activity_NumAdults, AdultNum)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Activity_NumChildren)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Activity_ChildAge1, ChildAge)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Activity_ChildAge2, ChildAge)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Activity_ChildAge3, ChildAge)

   <div class="submitbutton"> 
       <input data-inline="true"type="submit" id="activity_search" value="Search" />
   </div> 
 }
```

**Result View - Activities_FormSuccess**

```
@model Project.Models.ActivityModel

<p>City: @Model.Activity_CityName</p>
<p>StartDate: @Model.Activity_StartDate</p>
<p>EndDate: @Model.Activity_EndDate</p>

<div>
    <p><strong>Ticket</strong></p>
    <p>Number of Adults: @Model.Activity_NumAdults</p>
    <p>Number of Children: @Model.Activity_NumChildren</p>
    <p>Child 1 age: @Model.Activity_ChildAge1</p>
    <p>Child 2 age: @Model.Activity_ChildAge2</p>
    <p>Child 3 age: @Model.Activity_ChildAge3</p>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Activities()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Activities(ActivityModel activitysubmission)
{
    return View("Activities_FormSuccess", activitysubmission);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should store the posted model in the post action in session and restore it when you are showing the form to user.

```
public ActionResult Activities()
{
    if(Session["Activities"] != null)
    {
       var activityModel = (ActivityModel)Session["Activities"];
       return View(activityModel );
    }
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Activities(ActivityModel activitysubmission)
{
    ...
    Session["Activities"] = activitysubmission;
    return View("Activities_FormSuccess", activitysubmission);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I was able to get it to work for the most part. Do I just set Session["Activites"] = null when the person logs out?

Answer (score 2):

The way I handle this is with the session object that gets passed in between controller functions (likely where the user's logged in status is maintained, as well). When the user clicks 'finish this form later' or whatever, either save the form, form's values, or form serialized as JSON into the session. Whenever the form page loads, check if that variable exists in the session; if so, prepopulate your form with that data; else, display blank.

Comment: ah ok makes sense. I don't want to waste too much of your time, but would it be ok if you provided a short example or directed me to one? I'm quite an inexperienced programmer.

Comment: I don't have any experience in asp.net myself, you'll have to google around yourself a little. Maybe [some](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx) [of](http://wiki.asp.net/page.aspx/57/session/) [these](http://blogs.planetcloud.co.uk/mygreatdiscovery/post/Abstracting-session-in-ASPNET-MVC.aspx) might get you started?

Comment: @Mark below seems familiar with the Session framework, try applying my logic to his syntax and see what you come up with.

Answer (score 1):

Store the information you want within some form of 'Session' value and then check for existance within this when you return to this view and populate if applicable.

Comment: ty for the response! Is there any examples you could direct me to concerning this?